# Resubscribe an email address in Campaign Monitor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

Has anyone had success in resubscribing an email address after being unsubscribed via the Campaign Monitor API.

I ask as i want to keep a list of Active User's email addresses in my CM Active List. When they are suspended they get removed, when they join or pay their fees before getting deleted they are (re)subscribed.

Looking at the Rails API docs:

```
# File lib/campaign_monitor.rb, line 241
    def remove_subscriber(email)
      response = @cm_client.Subscriber_Unsubscribe("ListID" => @id, "Email" => email)
      Result.new(response["Message"], response["Code"].to_i)
    end

# File lib/campaign_monitor.rb, line 445
    def unsubscribe(list_id)
      response = @cm_client.Subscriber_Unsubscribe("ListID" => list_id, "Email" => @email_address)
      Result.new(response["Message"], response["Code"].to_i)
    end
```

On the CM website to move an email in the subscriber list to the active list you need to confirm you have permission to resubscribe them, can anyone say for sure that this applies to the API too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found the Subscriber.AddAndResubscribe method, undocumented in http://campaignmonitor.rubyforge.org/